# How can I simulate a capacitive touch with an Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am in the course of integrating a humidifier into my automation project, however to turn it on, a capacitive button has to be pushed, as I would like to avoid a mechanical construct, I have soldered a wire to the PCB, this in itself works fine, I touch the end of the wire - > machine turns on (actually it only turns one when I stop touching, I'm guessing this could be the issue).

Alternatively it also works if I touch the wire to ground.

How could I simulate this capacitive touch with an arduino to turn my humidifier on/off?

I have looked around a bit, most similar problems relate to triggering a touch on a screen.
I have then tried the following:

- writing an Arduino code to alternate the wire between float & ground

  ```
    int Pin = 2;
    void setup() {
    }

    void loop() {
      pinMode(Pin, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(Pin, HIGH);   
      delay(3000);                    
      pinMode(Pin, INPUT);
      digitalWrite(Pin, LOW);   
      delay(3000);                       
     }
  ```
- Additionally I tried tieing the wire to a wire attachted to the ground of the PCB with a MOSFET and switching this via the arduino.

Both attempts showed no reaction on the PCB side. To me it looks as if touching it to the arduino will change the attached capacity, but no matter what i do I can never release it (cause a state change)

P.S.: I don't understand much about these capacitive electronics.

Comment: Maybe use a QT Py? https://www.adafruit.com/product/4600

Comment: @MarkSetchell How would you wire and code this to get it to work though?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although it contains a bit of code, it's really about capacitative circuits and how to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I'm trying to do the same thing but with an air purifier. I was able to simulate capacitive touch by connecting the microcontroller ground to the collector of a 2N2222 transistor and Emitter to the capacitive touch pin corresponding to the ON/OFF button on the air purifier. I switched the connection on and off using a digital pin (like your situation, the purifier responds only after I stop touching).

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); //LED indicator
  pinMode(32, OUTPUT); //Transistor base
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(32, HIGH);
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(32, LOW);
  delay(3000);
}
```

I did notice however that it takes a couple cycles for the air purifier to start responding but after that it is pretty reliable. I only tried this once but I'm planning to integrate my purifier with HomeKit. I should also mention that my ESP32 was powered by the 5V and GND from the purifier itself (not sure if that matters).

EDIT: Nevermind, I made a small change in your script and it's now working without the need for an external transistor. I just set the pin to LOW in the setup and only toggled the pinMode in the loop like this:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); //internal LED for keeping track
  digitalWrite(32, LOW); //connected to capacitive pin on air purifier
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  pinMode(32, INPUT);
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  pinMode(32, OUTPUT);
  delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: Hello @tomdmt I stumbled across your answer, because I'm trying to make my Aiibot EPI188 Air Purifier smart as well. Which model of purifier is yours ?